# put several col* in a row in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want embed multiple `<div class"col-*">` in one `<div class="row">`element with these condition that exist padding left and right between `<div class"col-*">` elements.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
</div>
```

[see example](http://www.bootply.com/gmm9WjCUcZ)

Comment: What do you want exactly..?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: set white space between `col*` in left and right....

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a margin.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFQ3R/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 color"> sdf sdf sdfds sdf dsf ds fsd sfsd fsd </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"] {
  margin:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: give it in percentage accordingly. There might be a minor change in HTML, which would be pretty easy to handle.